# How to use the same ionic html for showing different images?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building wallpaper/gallery ionic app.I am trying to design app in such a way that users can click on the image shown as ionic card and and users will be shown the image in full screen probably using ionic slides with a button for downloading image below.

I know for a fact that using same code for displaying images full screen more than one time is not a good practice.

Is there any way i can use the same ionic slide code multiple times showing corresponding image full screen.

FYI,here is the code,

```
<ion-slidesj zoom="true">
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
      <img src="assets/img/dog.jpg">
    </div>
    <ion-label>Woof</ion-label>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
```

I want to use above same code multiple times with different img srcs for corresponding image user clicks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create `Angular/Ionic` `custom component` here.

```
ionic generate component MyImageSlider
```

After that wrap your image slider inside it and send your image URLs dynamically to that custom component when a user clicked the `ionic card`.

You can see how to create a [**custom Component**](https://www.joshmorony.com/custom-components-in-ionic-2/) here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to iterate through all your. Store all images path in a array of string and then iterate through that array. And pack your block of code in this loop .